# MySQL stored procedure the reason of rollback

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, error-handling, rollback

MySQL stored procedure will throw the error out if there is no `rollback` command for `SQLEXCEPTION`, but it has changed some data before the exception.
I add rollback command for SQL exceptions:

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK; 
END;
```

But I can not know the reason of the rollback now.
I know we can define every SQL exception and it's handler, but it's too complex and I just want to know why the rollback occurred.
Is there a simple method to get the reason of rollback in MySQL stored procedure?

Comment: What do you mean by rollback information?  Do you want to know what values were rolled back or why the rollback occurred?  Or Both?

Comment: @alan I just want know why the rollback occurred.

Comment: I don't understand why showing the errors before the rollback work for you.  Can you explain that in a bit more detail?

Comment: @alan I have tried this to get the rollback reason. But the result is empty, so I annotate it.

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to post what you attempted.

Comment: Have you tried RESIGNAL ? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resignal.html

Comment: @kordirko That's exactly what I need. Thanks. But it is not supported until MySQL 5.5. My MySQL server is 5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @kordirko. I have get one solution with RESIGNAL. But it is only supported until MySQL 5.5.

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
  SET @flag = 1;
  IF @flag = 1 THEN RESIGNAL;END IF;
  ROLLBACK;
END;
```